# Efficient set intersection to get rows in DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe with 3 values relevant to this question, `:ID`, `:Position`, `:Probability`. Each row is unique, but multiple rows may have the same `ID`. What I'd like to do is get all of the rows for a certain value of `Position`, that share an `ID` with any row that has a `Probability` higher than some value in a different position.

For example, say I have the following DataFrame (df):

```
1020692×8 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row     │ ID  │ Position      │ Probability │
├─────────┼─────┼───────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1       │ 425 │ "first"       │ 0.02        │
│ 2       │ 425 │ "last"        │ 0.03        │
│ 3       │ 425 │ "penultimate" │ 0.02        │
│ 4       │ 425 │ "other"       │ 0.04        │
│ 5       │ 421 │ "first"       │ 0.44        │
│ 6       │ 421 │ "last"        │ 0.85        │
│ 7       │ 421 │ "second"      │ 0.59        │
│ 8       │ 421 │ "other"       │ 1.0         │
⋮
```

If I set a threshold of `0.8`, I want to end up with all of the rows where `:Position == "first"` if that `:ID` has `:Position == "last" && :Probability > 0.8`. In other words, I'd want row 5, since row 6 has a `:Probability > 0.8`, but not row 1, since row 2 does not.

The row to check the threshold will not always follow the row I want to keep. Not all rows where `:Position == "first"` will have a `"last"` row to check, but there will be at most one.

The way I tried to solve this was to make a vector of all the `ID`s in `last` position with `Probability > 0.8`, and then tried to subset the dataframe using `in()`. So...

```
firsts = df[df[:Position] .== "first", :]
lasts = df[df[:Position] .== "last", :]
meetsthreshold = lasts[lasts[:Probability] .> 0.8, :ID]

final = firsts[[in(i, meetsthreshold) for i in firsts[:ID]], :]
```

I tested this with a super short vector of `ID`s and it works, but it lags super hard on my actual data (where `length(meetsthreshold)` is > 100k). I think what I want is basically a set intersection, and if I do that with the `ID`s(eg `intersect(Set(firsts[:ID]), Set(meetsthreshold))`) it's basically instantaneous. Is there a way to do the set intersection with a dataframe so I can actually get the rows?

Comment: My hint would be try: `by(g->maximum(g[:Probability])>0.9 ? g[g[:Position].=="first        ",:] : DataFrame(),df,:ID)`. But it's messy. Look at `by` and `groupby`.

Comment: Interesting idea - I've used `by` for a few things, but I don't quite grok the syntax of what you wrote... That's a pared down if-else statement in there right?

Comment: Yeah. It's a shorthand for an `if` statement. Did you try running it?

Comment: Yeah - it's running now... been about 5 minutes. See my answer below - it turns out if I make `meetsthreshold` a `Set`, my previous code goes super fast. I'm not marking my answer though if you want to expand on yours a bit.

Comment: Killed it after ~10 minutes...

Comment: Oh... it was just a vague suggestion. Anyway.. it solves a slightly different problem (not checking only the `"last"` row in `ID`). And perhaps it works faster on Julia 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kinda feel like an idiot - the solution is just use a set instead of a vector to search in. Eg:

```
firsts = df[df[:Position] .== "first", :]
lasts = df[df[:Position] .== "last", :]
meetsthreshold = Set(lasts[lasts[:Probability] .> 0.8, :ID])

final = firsts[Vector{Bool}([in(i, meetsthreshold) for i in firsts[:ID]]), :]
```

Ran in ~ 1 second.

Comment: Since it's been 6 months with no other replies, I went ahead and marked this answered.